# Add element in an ArrayList efficiently at a given index in java

Tags: java, performance, arraylist

I need to insert a element of type Person (my own defined class) in an ArrayList at index i

I know I can use [`add(int index, E element)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29).

But is there any efficient method to do this as in my list it is taking around 1.5 ms on an average (data collected over 1000 insertion and then average).

Comment: Well how big is your list? If you insert data early into a very large list, you'll be copying a lot of data...

Comment: Do you mean - is there a list implementation that is more efficient for insertion?

Comment: I'd be surprised if there would be a more efficient way using ArrayList. Core functions should be optomized pretty well. Plus do you consider 1.5 ms slow?

Comment: `LinkedList` is much more appropriate for insertion/deletion in a list than an `ArrayList`.

Comment: more than 100,00 element arre there already in list and I am adding 1 element every 20ms.
1.5 ms is average and according to my requirement it is slow.

I need to insert at an particular index so I guess arraylist will be much better as for array it gives around 0.02 - 0.1 ms 
(I know array list need to expand and all but still)

Comment: @GuillaumePolet while you are correct that insertion would not require copying of data in a `LinkedList`; finding the index `n` would be an `O(n)` operation as you have to walk the `List`. I suspect that `System.arraycopy` might have a faster constant factor and hence still be faster.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I have tried but not succeded to write code with System.array as I was not able to expand my Arraylist for proper size 
can you give code example on using System.arraycopy for arraylist

Thanks

Comment: @b.pradeep `ArrayList` already uses `System.arraycopy` internally - there is no reason for you to user it yourself.

Comment: so there isn't any way to make it faster ???

Comment: It seems like you have only given part of the requirements. You need to do a binary search to find the insert point? So this is a sorted list? Then you need a different data structure I think. Consider a TreeSet.

Comment: @BoristheSpider the `indexOf` implementation of an `ArrayList` is also `an O(n)`. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist) for the full-comparison. My statement was only about add/remove operations.

Answer (score 10):

If your task is more insertion / deletion intensive, you can always use [java.util.LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

- ArrayList has a limited size. Every time you add an element, Java ensures that it can fit - so it grows the ArrayList. If the ArrayList grows faster, there will be a lot of array copying taking place.
- LinkedList just adds the element to the correct place (linking the nodes around), without growing and copying of the whole ArrayList.
- Drawbacks of the LinkedList are when you are searching for an element. Since it has no indexes, it must traverse from the beginning to the end of the list to find an item.

For `LinkedList`:

- get is O(n)
- add is O(1)
- remove is O(n)
- Iterator.remove is O(1)

For `ArrayList`:

- get is O(1)
- add is O(1) amortized, but O(n) worst-case since the array must be resized and copied
- remove is O(n)

Comment: I need to first do a binary search to find index and then need to insert,

I can't use Linkedlist as what I am doing is to insert in tableview which is using arraylist as underlying model (ObservableList<S>).

Comment: Can you be more specific on the TableView?

Comment: This is a copy of this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist) (which is much more detailed)

Comment: @GuillaumePolet +1 I have already check that answer before asking my question

Answer (score 0):

This insertion is happening in O(n) because it has to shift all the elements down and worst case scenario it will shift every element down. (Corrected java says it is O(n) because they use a mathematical formula to insert)

If you want a fast insertion either add it at the end of the arraylist or use a hashmap which is constant time.

Insert into hashmap:
HashMap  peopleMap = new Hashmap.....

peopleMap.put(person.name, person);
//(or whatever you want to track)

This sets the key to th persons name and the value to person.

You can also try a hashmap with key (ehatver you want to track) and value the index where the person is in a holder array. The insert is O(i), lookup O(i) and you can sort it as well (I'll leave this as an exercise to the reader)

If the whole purpose of this is to sort, then for simplicity you could insert into a priorityQueue (nLogn) then pop everything into the array which will give you a sorted array

Comment: how can it be O(n^2) I need to shift complete array i will start from end. I guess this is how System.arraycopy work and it is really fast

Comment: `put(index, value);` where index is the key

Comment: @waf but that actually depend on way of implementation if what you are saying is always correct then insertion sort will be O(n^3)
isn't it ?

Comment: Just read the details of Java's implementation and it is O(n) due to some formula they use for insert

Answer (score -2):

If you add using

```
arryListInstance.add(positionIndex, Object);
```

the object will be added after sifting the existing objects by 1 position. Therefore average case of this operation become *O(n)*.

While simple add

```
arryListInstance.add(positionIndex, Object);
```

adds the object at the end of the arrayListInstance. At it's best case this operation is *O(1)*, but at it's worst case it becomes *O(n)* when the maximum capacity is reached: as a new ArrayList instance is created internally and all the contents are copied there.

You are facing this issue because one of the two reasons of which 1st can be avoided:

1. You have not defined sufficient initial capacity for your ArrayList object. Therefore, before every *arrayListInstance.add(positionIndex, object)* a **new arrayListInstance** is being created with increased capacity and then the existing elements from the original list are being copied and then finally *add* is being performed. This can be avoided, if you know exactly how much data you want to handle by this list and define initial capacity accordingly (same as number of possible elments). If you cann't predict the initial capacity then it's better to process data in ***batches***.
2. After every insert at any position except the last causes sifting of existing elements. This is unavoidable. Therefore, *arrayListInstance.add(positionIndex, object)* will be performed in *O(n)* time if *positionIndex* is not the last index of the arrayList. Even if you use *LinkedList* you cann't achieve constant time add operation which adds an element into the list at an index other than after the last element.

Comment: You are using the same add in both cases, thus the down vote.  The second add is not the "simple" add.

Comment: should be arryListInstance.add(Object);