# Java List Horrible Adding Performance

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, addition

I'm adding millions of entries of a custom object to a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html). This turns out to be very slow and the graphical user interface keeps freezing randomly as well (not responding on Windows) even though the adding operation is wrapped in a `SwingWorker` so it should not affect the [EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). Furthermore, the `CPU` utilization goes up to around 70% - 90%.

I'm initializing the list as follows:

```
List<SearchResult> updatedSearchResults = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then I'm repeatedly calling

```
SearchResult searchResult = new SearchResult(...);
updatedSearchResults.add(searchResult);
```

to add elements.

I'm aware that the [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) internally uses an array which is resized when it is full and all elements are copied over. However, using a [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) has shown to be slower than the `ArrayList` though and no other List implementation exists.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17146486/3764804) answer, adding to an `ArrayList` has a performance of `O(1)`. The question arises why my approach of collecting all results is still so awful performance-wise. `SearchResult` is a simple data object encapsulating fields and initializing it is cheap since only fields are set.

As comparison, adding to the list is noticeably slower than sending the same amount of data over a network socket. This doesn't make any sense since local operations should always be way faster than network related operations.

`1 million` elements finishes in about `0.2 seconds` but `67 million` won't even finish in a reasonable amount of time. It should finish like a few seconds at maximum.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListPerformanceTester
{
    public enum ValueSize
    {
        EIGHT_BIT("8-Bit"),
        SIXTEEN_BIT("16-Bit"),
        THIRTY_TWO_BIT("32-Bit"),
        SIXTY_FOUR_BIT("64-Bit"),
        NINETY_SIX_BIT("96-Bit");

        private String name;

        ValueSize(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getBytesCount()
        {
            switch (this)
            {
                case EIGHT_BIT:
                    return 1;

                case SIXTEEN_BIT:
                    return 2;

                case THIRTY_TWO_BIT:
                    return 4;

                case SIXTY_FOUR_BIT:
                    return 8;

                case NINETY_SIX_BIT:
                    return 12;
            }

            throw new IllegalStateException("Bytes count undefined for " + this);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return name;
        }

        public static ValueSize parse(String name)
        {
            ValueSize[] valueSizes = values();

            for (ValueSize valueSize : valueSizes)
            {
                String currentName = valueSize.toString();

                if (currentName.equals(name))
                {
                    return valueSize;
                }
            }

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No value size associated");
        }
    }

    public static class SearchResult implements Cloneable, Comparable
    {
        private int address;
        private ValueSize valueSize;
        private BigInteger previousValue;
        private BigInteger currentValue;
        private BigInteger valueDifference;

        public SearchResult(int address, BigInteger previousValue,
                            BigInteger currentValue, ValueSize valueSize)
        {
            this.address = address;
            this.valueSize = valueSize;
            this.previousValue = previousValue;
            this.currentValue = currentValue;

            setValueDifference();
        }

        private void setValueDifference()
        {
            BigInteger subtractionResult = previousValue.subtract(currentValue);
            valueDifference = subtractionResult.abs();
        }

        private byte[] getBytes(BigInteger bigInteger) throws IOException
        {
            byte[] retrieved = bigInteger.toByteArray();
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int bytesCount = getValueSize().getBytesCount();
            int paddingBytes = bytesCount - retrieved.length;

            if (paddingBytes >= 0)
            {
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(new byte[paddingBytes]);
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(retrieved);
            } else
            {
                writeWithoutLeadingNullBytes(byteArrayOutputStream, retrieved);
            }

            return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        }

        private void writeWithoutLeadingNullBytes(ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream, byte[] bytes)
        {
            int index = 0;
            boolean nonNullByteFound = false;

            while (index < bytes.length)
            {
                byte value = bytes[index];

                if (value != 0 || nonNullByteFound)
                {
                    nonNullByteFound = true;
                    byteArrayOutputStream.write(value);
                }

                index++;
            }
        }

        public int getAddress()
        {
            return address;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object object)
        {
            if (!(object instanceof SearchResult))
            {
                return false;
            }

            SearchResult searchResult = (SearchResult) object;

            return searchResult.getAddress() == getAddress();
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode()
        {
            return Integer.hashCode(address);
        }

        public ValueSize getValueSize()
        {
            return valueSize;
        }

        @Override
        public SearchResult clone()
        {
            return new SearchResult(address, previousValue, currentValue, valueSize);
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Object object)
        {
            return new Integer(address).compareTo(((SearchResult) object).getAddress());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments)
    {
        long milliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int elementsCount = 2000000;

        /*List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int elementIndex = 0; elementIndex < elementsCount; elementIndex++)
        {
            list.add(0);
        }*/

        List<SearchResult> searchResults = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int elementIndex = 0; elementIndex < elementsCount; elementIndex++)
        {
            SearchResult searchResult = new SearchResult(0x12345678, new BigInteger("3"), new BigInteger("1"), ValueSize.EIGHT_BIT);
            searchResults.add(searchResult);
        }

        System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - milliseconds) / (double) 1000 + " seconds");
    }
}
```

What is the big issue here?

Comment: The first obvious thing to do would be to specify the right size for the List from the start, but I suspect the problem is actually elsewhere: does your JVM have enough memory for those millions of elements? What do they contain? What does the constructor do. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: How long does it take to add the same item to the list 67M times? That's how long it takes to do the *adding*. All the rest of the time in your current code is other stuff, like creating the elements to put in the list.

Comment: Use a profiler like visualvm in the jdk to identify the bottleneck. You might be surprised

Comment: @AndyTurner: Yeah, that only takes `0.53 seconds`. I also posted a complete example

Comment: A `List` is probably the wrong data structure for millions of elements.

Comment: `BigInteger` turns out to be the bottleneck here

Comment: Use BigDecimal.valueOf(3) instead of new BigDecimal("3"), and you should see a substantial difference. That said, it just takes 2.5 seconds to run your code on my machine.

Comment: @JBNizet Probably because you have enough memory. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41411545/5221149).

Comment: @Andreas I upvoted it. Running it with 67M instead of 2M, even with BigDecimal.valueOf(3) obviously causes memory issues.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're running out of memory and the JVM begins continuous Garbage Collection.

To show this, I created this program:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (long i = 0; i < 100_000_000; i++) {
            if (i % 1_000_000 == 0)
                System.out.printf("%9d: %d ms%n", i, System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
            list.add(new Long(i));
        }
        System.out.printf("Total    : %d ms%n", System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
    }
}
```

I running with jdk1.8.0_91, 64-bit on Windows 10.

Running with options `-XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xmx1g`, I see:

```
        0: 1 ms
[GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 29801K->5117K(38400K)] 29801K->22565K(125952K), 0.0133554 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
  1000000: 31 ms
[GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 38397K->5120K(71680K)] 55845K->48026K(159232K), 0.0196297 secs] [Times: user=0.13 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
  2000000: 62 ms
  3000000: 71 ms
[GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 71680K->5104K(71680K)] 114586K->104090K(171008K), 0.0391813 secs] [Times: user=0.34 sys=0.03, real=0.04 secs] 
[Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 5104K->0K(71680K)] [ParOldGen: 98986K->96640K(216064K)] 104090K->96640K(287744K), [Metaspace: 2754K->2754K(1056768K)], 0.5258703 secs] [Times: user=1.59 sys=0.00, real=0.53 secs] 
  4000000: 643 ms
  5000000: 650 ms
[GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 66560K->5120K(99328K)] 163200K->162716K(315392K), 0.0463488 secs] [Times: user=0.36 sys=0.02, real=0.05 secs] 
... 30 lines removed ...
 28000000: 8269 ms
 29000000: 8273 ms
 30000000: 8277 ms
[Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 140722K->140712K(232960K)] [ParOldGen: 699038K->699038K(699392K)] 839760K->839750K(932352K), [Metaspace: 2768K->2768K(1056768K)], 2.1019108 secs] [Times: user=14.30 sys=0.06, real=2.10 secs] 
[Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 140722K->140722K(232960K)] [ParOldGen: 699038K->699038K(699392K)] 839760K->839760K(932352K), [Metaspace: 2768K->2768K(1056768K)], 1.9041177 secs] [Times: user=12.95 sys=0.02, real=1.90 secs] 
[Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 140722K->140722K(232960K)] [ParOldGen: 699038K->699038K(699392K)] 839760K->839760K(932352K), [Metaspace: 2768K->2768K(1056768K)], 1.9111176 secs] [Times: user=13.13 sys=0.02, real=1.91 secs] 
[Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 140722K->140722K(232960K)] [ParOldGen: 699039K->699039K(699392K)] 839762K->839762K(932352K), [Metaspace: 2768K->2768K(1056768K)], 1.8883737 secs] [Times: user=12.72 sys=0.03, real=1.89 secs] 
[Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 140722K->140722K(232960K)] [ParOldGen: 699041K->699041K(699392K)] 839763K->839763K(932352K), [Metaspace: 2768K->2768K(1056768K)], 1.8866147 secs] [Times: user=13.01 sys=0.00, real=1.89 secs] 
[Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 140722K->140722K(232960K)] [ParOldGen: 699042K->699042K(699392K)] 839765K->839765K(932352K), [Metaspace: 2768K->2768K(1056768K)], 1.8867966 secs] [Times: user=12.70 sys=0.03, real=1.89 secs] 
... program killed by me ...
```

If I preallocate memory using `-XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xmx1g -Xms1g`, I see:

```
        0: 1 ms
  1000000: 19 ms
  2000000: 36 ms
  3000000: 49 ms
... 30 lines remove ...
 29000000: 6320 ms
 30000000: 6324 ms
 31000000: 6328 ms
[Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 157018K->152753K(305664K)] [ParOldGen: 699350K->699350K(699392K)] 856368K->852103K(1005056K), [Metaspace: 2769K->2769K(1056768K)], 2.0326459 secs] [Times: user=13.84 sys=0.05, real=2.03 secs] 
[Full GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 152753K->152753K(305664K)] [ParOldGen: 699350K->699338K(699392K)] 852103K->852091K(1005056K), [Metaspace: 2769K->2769K(1056768K)], 1.9620070 secs] [Times: user=12.70 sys=0.05, real=1.96 secs] 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3210)
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3181)
    at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:261)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:235)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:227)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:458)
    at Test.main(Test.java:13)
Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 305664K, used 162579K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 262144K, 62% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000f49c4c90,0x00000000fab00000)
  from space 43520K, 0% used [0x00000000fab00000,0x00000000fab00000,0x00000000fd580000)
  to   space 43520K, 0% used [0x00000000fd580000,0x00000000fd580000,0x0000000100000000)
 ParOldGen       total 699392K, used 699338K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000eab00000)
  object space 699392K, 99% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000eaaf28d0,0x00000000eab00000)
 Metaspace       used 2800K, capacity 4486K, committed 4864K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 305K, capacity 386K, committed 512K, reserved 1048576K
```

Running with enough memory using `-XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xmx5g -Xms5g`, program completes normally and fast:

```
        0: 0 ms
  1000000: 18 ms
  2000000: 35 ms
  3000000: 47 ms
  4000000: 55 ms
  5000000: 69 ms
  6000000: 77 ms
  7000000: 95 ms
  8000000: 102 ms
  9000000: 110 ms
 10000000: 132 ms
 11000000: 140 ms
 12000000: 148 ms
 13000000: 156 ms
 14000000: 185 ms
 15000000: 193 ms
 16000000: 201 ms
 17000000: 209 ms
 18000000: 217 ms
 19000000: 224 ms
 20000000: 232 ms
 21000000: 273 ms
 22000000: 281 ms
 23000000: 289 ms
 24000000: 297 ms
 25000000: 305 ms
 26000000: 313 ms
 27000000: 320 ms
 28000000: 330 ms
 29000000: 338 ms
 30000000: 346 ms
 31000000: 364 ms
[GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1145973K->218085K(1529344K)] 1145973K->854725K(5024768K), 0.5204458 secs] [Times: user=3.50 sys=0.20, real=0.52 secs] 
 32000000: 922 ms
 33000000: 927 ms
 34000000: 931 ms
 35000000: 936 ms
 36000000: 940 ms
 37000000: 945 ms
 38000000: 949 ms
 39000000: 953 ms
 40000000: 957 ms
 41000000: 962 ms
 42000000: 966 ms
 43000000: 970 ms
 44000000: 975 ms
 45000000: 979 ms
 46000000: 984 ms
 47000000: 1028 ms
 48000000: 1032 ms
 49000000: 1037 ms
 50000000: 1041 ms
 51000000: 1045 ms
 52000000: 1049 ms
 53000000: 1053 ms
 54000000: 1057 ms
 55000000: 1061 ms
 56000000: 1065 ms
 57000000: 1069 ms
 58000000: 1073 ms
 59000000: 1077 ms
 60000000: 1085 ms
 61000000: 1093 ms
 62000000: 1101 ms
 63000000: 1109 ms
 64000000: 1117 ms
 65000000: 1125 ms
 66000000: 1133 ms
 67000000: 1141 ms
[GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1529317K->218096K(1529344K)] 2165957K->1851537K(5024768K), 0.9403854 secs] [Times: user=5.70 sys=1.11, real=0.94 secs] 
 68000000: 2088 ms
 69000000: 2094 ms
 70000000: 2099 ms
 71000000: 2165 ms
 72000000: 2169 ms
 73000000: 2173 ms
 74000000: 2177 ms
 75000000: 2183 ms
 76000000: 2188 ms
 77000000: 2193 ms
 78000000: 2199 ms
 79000000: 2204 ms
 80000000: 2209 ms
 81000000: 2214 ms
 82000000: 2219 ms
 83000000: 2225 ms
 84000000: 2230 ms
 85000000: 2235 ms
 86000000: 2240 ms
 87000000: 2244 ms
 88000000: 2248 ms
 89000000: 2252 ms
 90000000: 2256 ms
 91000000: 2260 ms
 92000000: 2265 ms
 93000000: 2270 ms
 94000000: 2275 ms
 95000000: 2280 ms
 96000000: 2286 ms
 97000000: 2291 ms
 98000000: 2296 ms
 99000000: 2302 ms
Total    : 2307 ms
Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 1529344K, used 1423154K [0x0000000755580000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1311232K, 91% used [0x0000000755580000,0x000000079ee50960,0x00000007a5600000)
  from space 218112K, 99% used [0x00000007b2b00000,0x00000007bfffc010,0x00000007c0000000)
  to   space 218112K, 0% used [0x00000007a5600000,0x00000007a5600000,0x00000007b2b00000)
 ParOldGen       total 3495424K, used 1633441K [0x0000000680000000, 0x0000000755580000, 0x0000000755580000)
  object space 3495424K, 46% used [0x0000000680000000,0x00000006e3b28508,0x0000000755580000)
 Metaspace       used 2802K, capacity 4486K, committed 4864K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 302K, capacity 386K, committed 512K, reserved 1048576K
```

Comment: Using the VM arguments indeed makes everything run significantly faster even for my example code from the original post hence +1